# using Application_Start over HttpApplication constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC 4.0` project that I am working on, and I notice that by default, the `global.asax` file looks like this ...

```
namespace Application1.Web {
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any specific reason I would want to use `Application_Start` instead of just putting this in the constructor? I have done it both ways unknowingly, and have never experienced a problem with either.

This question does not aim to solve a problem, merely to get information that I lack. If it is redundant, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else may be able to provide a more in depth answer, but, some methods such as `Begin_Request` will be executed per request.  `Session_Start` will be executed at the beginning of each users session.

However, `Application_Start` is only executed once, and as a result, it is thread safe.  If you were to move those calls to the constructor, those methods would be executed for every request since that object would be instantiated for each request.

Here is a snippet from the [ASP.NET Application Lifecycle page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> After all core application objects have been initialized, the application is started by creating an instance of the HttpApplication class. **If the application has a Global.asax file, ASP.NET instead creates an instance of the Global.asax class that is derived from the HttpApplication class and uses the derived class to represent the application**.